# Explanation of this code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

I've just come across the following code which I can't understand:

```
var dataItem = (SportNode)item.DataItem;
item.FindControl<Literal>("Node", image =>
    image.Text = string.Format("<li data-nodeId='{1}' class='{0}'><a href='/sport?navItems={3}'>{2}</a></li>", "top",
    dataItem.NodeId, dataItem.Text, dataItem.NodeId));
```

In particular, where does image come from?  It's not declared anywhere yet seems to have a type.  I certainly can't see it in any parent classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"image" is the input parameter to the lambda expression.

Read more on lambdas [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

For a more readable and in-depth look at lambdas, [Scott Guthrie has a great post introducing them](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/08/new-orcas-language-feature-lambda-expressions.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Image, here, is the parameter to an anonymous function - it derives its type from the signature of whatever you are passing it in to; for instance:

```
    private void PrintResult(Func<Int32, Int32> f)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(f.Invoke(1));
    }

    //In some other method
    PrintResult(n => n + 2); //prints 3
```

You can look up more about this if you'd like - I'd search for "Lambda expression" or "anonymous function."

Answer (score 1):

This is an anonymous method. `image` is the name of the parameter to this method. The type of `image` is inferred from the second parameter of `FindControl`.